# How to convert mpp to pdf in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ms-project, mpp

I want to convert my mpp file to pdf in C# .net code. I have already tried

```
appclass.DocumentExport(FileUploadFolderPath + "\\" + fileName, MPP.PjDocExportType.pjPDF, true, true, false);
```

And this works fine in my local system, but doesn't work when run from my server(maybe because the file is not quitting then how can i make it quit).I am using VS 2017 and .net version 3.1.24.
Checked print (pdf) driver . it is there in the server. the error comes from line

appclass.DocumentExport(FileUploadFolderPath + "" + fileName, MPP.PjDocExportType.pjPDF, true, true, false);

Request Object: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x000003EC): An unexpected error occurred with the method.

I have already tried adding

```
appclass.Quit();
```

And after few calls to the api my mpp file is also not getting created, I have used the following code to create mpp

```
appclass.FileSaveAs(FileUploadFolderPath + "\\" + fileName); 
appclass.FileClose(Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjSaveType.pjSave);
```

Comment: You should really reformat and clarify your problem. How is not working? Does it throw any exception?

Comment: Thankyou for your reply and feedback, will reformat my question. Actually this is after my code got deployed. It's not showing any error but just not responding and pdf is not getting created

Comment: Have you tried to debug it step by step? Also, you should check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Publisher.Document.SaveAs), it's for VB but it's the same principle for C#.

Comment: Yes I have tried debugging, its after i have used the following code that its not responding appclass.Quit();... yes I have checked that link ... but mpp has only FileSaveAs and it's not working to converting to pdf

Comment: If it's working on your local machine and not when run from the server, perhaps the server does not have a print (pdf) driver installed.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Checked print (pdf) driver . it is there in the server. the error comes from line

appclass.DocumentExport(FileUploadFolderPath + "" + fileName, MPP.PjDocExportType.pjPDF, true, true, false);

Request Object: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x000003EC): An unexpected error occurred with the method.

Comment: @AnuM Hard to say if it's the DocumentExport method or the path or something else. So try variations of the code such as exporting to XPS format, exporting to a different (simpler) path and file name. Try doing a SaveAs to that path, etc.